# deploy war in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, weceem

I have a very strange error, I finished my project, made the .war file, but when I put it in the Tomcat_HOME/webapps folder, and it also deploys, but it's not showing up in the browser, instead it gives me the 404 error: The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Is the app started and running? Have you checked that in /manager?

Comment: i deploy it in tomcat , i noticed that running status is false , and didn't show me the browser , however i deploy another war and its work properly

Comment: Take a look at the logs. There has got to be a startup failure with the application.

Comment: first time i upload the file , tomcat error was that file exceed the maximum size , so i change the file web.xml and set max size value larger .. in log files this error : SEVERE: HTMLManager: FAIL - Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (52983268) exceeds the configured maximum (52428800)

Comment: now i just have this error in log SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Comment: can you post the contents of your catalina.out file?? its located in logs folder.

Comment: Mar 09, 2014 7:49:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 09, 2014 7:49:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/weceem-1.2-M1] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: im give up with error increasing :(

Comment: @user3396871 The error listenerStart means the real error is further up in the error log

Comment: Is this a Grails war?  I get the listenerStart when the Datasource is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that probably you didn't configure Weceem configuration file location, check http://www.weceem.org/weceem/documentation/Installation for details. If you don't want to spend time for preparing separate configuration, you can get example of weceem.properties file from weceem-1.2-M1.war (in should be in root of WAR file) and put it in the root of web applications of your tomcat server, e.g.

```
apache-tomcat-7.xx/webapps/weceem-1.2-M1.war
apache-tomcat-7.xx/webapps/weceem.properties
```

Of cause, in your application you can specify any other path, but see Weceem demo as an example.